# What does CAP_NET_RAW do?

Tags: linux, networking

From the man page, I know you can use raw sockets, but I don’t understand what is meant by “bind to any address for transparent proxying”. I know there’s another capability required to bind to privileged ports, so I know you can’t bind to any port. Is there a way to tell Linux that you’re binding on an address for proxying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [this Security SE Answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/128988/82570):

> **CAP_NET_RAW**: Any kind of packet can be forged, which includes faking senders, sending malformed packets, etc., this also allows to bind to any address (associated to the ability to fake a sender this allows to impersonate a device, legitimately used for "transparent proxying" as per the manpage but from an attacker point-of-view this term is a synonym for Man-in-The-Middle),

Comment: Hmm does that mean, say if your actual public ip is 1.1.1.1 and you want to impersonate some other web server with 2.2.2.2, you can bind a socket on 2.2.2.2:80? in essence, this capability allows you to carry out man-in-the-middle attacks?

Comment: Yes, *if* the traffic for server 2.2.2.2 is already getting routed through your server for any reason. In legitimate use as a transparent proxy, a router/gateway or a firewall device would be configured to redirect any transparent-proxyable traffic to your server instead of their actual destination; in an evil scenario, you would have to place the server in the right position in the victim network or execute some sort of traffic rerouting attack before using this capability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

> Socket options
>
> ...
>
> IP_FREEBIND (since Linux 2.4)
>
> If enabled, this boolean option allows binding to an IP
>                 address that is nonlocal or does not (yet) exist.  This per‐
>                 mits listening on a socket, without requiring the underlying
>                 network interface or the specified dynamic IP address to be up
>                 at the time that the application is trying to bind to it.
>                 This option is the per-socket equivalent of the ip_nonlo‐
>                 cal_bind /proc interface described below.

see also

> IP_TRANSPARENT (since Linux 2.6.24)
>
> Setting this boolean option enables transparent proxying on
>                 this socket.  This socket option allows the calling applica‐
>                 tion to bind to a nonlocal IP address and operate both as a
>                 client and a server with the foreign address as the local end‐
>                 point.  NOTE: this requires that routing be set up in a way
>                 that packets going to the foreign address are routed through
>                 the TProxy box (i.e., the system hosting the application that
>                 employs the IP_TRANSPARENT socket option).  Enabling this
>                 socket option requires superuser privileges (the CAP_NET_ADMIN
>                 capability).
>
> TProxy redirection with the iptables TPROXY target also
>                 requires that this option be set on the redirected socket.

(based on the other man page, I guess *either* of CAP_NET_ADMIN or CAP_NET_RAW are sufficient.  And I would really hope they are required for IP_FREEBIND also).